# Python TCP sockets to make a chat

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make a chat in Py3 using tcp sockets but I'm kind of a noob…
How should I handle my sockets correctly to have them receive messages aswell as send them ?
Do I need to bind to a local port to send packages to an external machine ? 
Do I need to use different sockets to receive and send ?

I can not get my program to work to both receive and send (I'm getting some errors) but I have no problem sending on one instance and receiving on another.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the [mcve] guidelines.  "I'm getting some errors" isn't enough information to reproduce and solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not looking to solve an error, I'm my looking for answers to my questions. I have 134 lines of code I could throw in there but I don't see the point : all I really need is some insight on how to setup TCP sockets as to both listen for incoming data and send data.